# Can you jump in Tag?

Tags: tag-the-power-of-paint

There doesn't seem to be any options interface in the Tag: The Power of Paint, so I can't look up what it might be bound to, but is (paint unassisted) jumping impossible?

Eerily similar to Princess No-knees...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot jump.

You can, however:

- Gain momentum by using red paint (speed) on a slope to fling yourself upwards.
- Use green paint (bounce) to bounce upwards (but also climb upwards when used between two walls.)
- Also you've got the blue paint (sticky) to walk on walls/ceilings.

By Princess No-Knees you seem to refer to "Narbacular Drop", indeed there is no jumping there either.

Funny fact: Valve hired the Narbacular drop team to create portal (wherein you CAN jump!)

Funny fact2: Valve then hired the team that created "Tag" to help develop portal 2 (Also there is jumping).

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DontExplainTheJoke

Comment: Can you explain to me why you posted that link? :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to spray green paint, stepping on it causes your jump.

This works where red paint = speed up
and blue paint = climb/walk on anything